# Is there a general form for the relation between $df(x)$ and $dx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let's say that $f(x)$ is a function and $dx$ is a slight change in the input, $x$. It has been used here as standard calculus notation and hence, $dx \rightarrow 0$. $df$, or $df(x)$ is again, by standard calculus notation, the change in the value of $f(x)$ with the slight change in $x$ equal to $dx$ i.e. $df = f(x+dx) - f(x)$.

Now, I want to know if there is some general form for $df$ in terms of $dx$.

I have stated some examples below to make it clearer.
$$\text{If }f(x) = x^2 \implies df = (2x\cdot dx) + (dx)^2$$
$$\text{If }f(x) = x^3 \implies df = 3x(dx^2) + 3x^2(dx) + (dx)^3$$
$$\text{If }f(x) = \sin(x) \implies df = (\cos(x))\cdot dx$$
$$\text{If }f(x) = \cos(x) \implies df = (-\sin(x))\cdot dx$$

As far as I've noticed, for most of the functions, $df = a(dx) + b(dx)^2 + ... + k(dx)^n$, where $a \neq 0$. But, can there exist such a function that $df$ includes a constant term?

Let's assume that such a function exists. Let's call it $f_2$. Now, let's say that $df_2 = c + a(dx)$, where $c \in \Bbb R$. Now, how would we evaluate $f_2'(x)$ in this situation?

$f_2'(x) = \dfrac{df_2}{dx} = \dfrac{a+c(dx)}{dx} = \dfrac{a}{dx} + c$ as $dx \rightarrow 0$. So, does that mean that $f_2'(x) = \infty$?

---

**Edit (more on the intentions for posting this question)**

While deriving the power rule in one of his videos, Grant Sanderson (3Blue1Brown) considers $(df)(dg)$ as negligible but that didn't satisfy me much. So, while deriving $\dfrac{dx^2}{dx}$, I first simplified the RHS for the LHS being $\dfrac{dx^2}{dx}$ and the right hand side being $\dfrac{2x(dx)+(dx)^2}{dx} = 2x+dx$ as $dx\rightarrow 0$, which makes it equal to $2x$. Now, I thought of using the same for deriving $\dfrac{d((f(x)⋅g(x))}{dx}$ when it has been deduced that $d(f(x)⋅g(x)) = f(x)(dg) + g(x)(df) + (df)(dg)$.

Now, if I somehow, establish that $dx$ is a part of every single term in the expansion of $df$, then I can just take it out as a common part and then cancel it with the $dx$ in the denominator to have at least a single term without any power of $dx$. All the terms other than that term would then, collapse as they would all have $(dx)^n$ in them for $n \geq 1$ and as $dx \rightarrow 0$, those terms would approach $0$ as well. This would help me get a clearer view of the derivation and of differentiation itself.

---

Thanks!

Comment: If $df = f(x+dx) - f(x)$ then your examples for $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not right. Despite what you say this is not "standard calculus notation".

Comment: @ancientmathematician I know that $\sin(x+y)-\sin x \neq (\cos x)(y)$ but that is true when $y \rightarrow 0$, right? And by saying 'standard calculus notation', I meant that the quantity approaches zero. In a 3Blue1Brown video (in "Essence of Calculus"), Grant Sanderson (the person who runs the channel) used $dx$ for some quantity and said that it denoted that $dx \rightarrow 0$ and termed it as 'standard calculus notation'. I could easily have misinterpreted it. Should I use another term for the same?

Comment: A constant term would mean some increment $df$ of $f$ value could be arbitrarilyy big _independently_ on an increment $dx$ of its parameter $x$. Would that make any sense...?

Comment: @CiaPan Would it be resolved if it was $c + p(x) + a(dx)$ for $p \in \Bbb R$ for example?

Comment: For $dx=0$ you need $df=0$, independent on $x$. So your proposal would work for $p(x)=-c$ only, effectively cancelling the $c$ term.

Comment: Now, $dx = 0 \implies df = 0$ might be of great help. We know that $df$ depends on $dx$  and so, a general form of $df$ might be stated as $(dx)(r) + m$, where $m$ is independent of $dx$. Now, $m$ is either dependent on $x$ or it isn't. But, if it is dependent on $x$, then it is a function in terms of $n$,  which is not possible (as you deduced in your previous comment). This leaves the possibility of it being a constant, which is again, not possible as $dx=0 \implies df=0$ (as stated by you, again). This only leaves the possibility that $df$ 's expansion has $dx$ common in all terms.

Comment: The only loose end (according to me) is that in this context, $dx \neq 0$ because $dx$ approaches $0$, but never really equals it...

Comment: You can see that a lot of this is nonsense by comparing what you write for $f(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=\sin x$: in one you allow the $(dx)^2$ terms, but in the other you treat them as negligible and throw them away. Analysis needs a lot more care and a lot less juggling with formulas. Or so it seems to  me.

Comment: @ancientmathematician At first, I include the terms with powers of $dx$ greater than $1$ in the expansion of $df$ and then while simplifying $\dfrac{df}{dx}$, I eliminate the terms that include $dx$ post-simplification as $dx \rightarrow 0$ and hence, any term with it as a multiple approaches $0$ and the term previously with the power of $dx$ as $1$ remains because $dx$ gets cancelled out. Is that understandable?

Comment: The problem is that  your post uses "$=$" in a very confusing way. Seriously, this is not mathematics you are doing, it's notation-juggling. There are two good answers explaining what one needs to do to turn this into something genuine: but your comments suggest that you are not prepared to listen.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you kindly tell which two answers you're referring to so that I can think harder about them? Can you also give an example where $=$ makes my post confusing so that I can clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Have you looked at the way these derivatives are actually calculated using limits?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Yes, $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}  \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$. But, what is wrong with the intuitive method (other than  the notation)? I'm really confused after *ancientmathematician*'s comments.

Comment: Yes. As you can see, in the formal calculus writing the symbol $dx$ does not appear on its own, nor does the symbol $df$. Hence it's not easy to address your question about the symbols $df$ and $dx$: they are a good heuristic sometimes, but as soon as you start asking what do they mean and how to manipulate them you get into trouble, as you already did. If you are going to work with limits (as most people do) you need to do everything with limits and forget infinitesimals.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I see, thank you! I might just have understood about the drawbacks of infinitesimals too but they sure are good for a layman and for intuition,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented on a previous post of yours, one should keep in mind that writing expressions such as $\frac{a+c\cdot dx}{dx}$ *really* is taking notation too seriously, since the derivative is not a fraction and so on.

However, with the right interpretation one can kind of make sense of (at least  some of) such manipulations. In this view, then the equation
$$df=a+c(dx)$$
(where $a$ is not an infinitesimal) doesn't make sense because on the left hand side you have an infinitesimal, and on the right hand side you have a nonzero constant (which cannot be infinitesimal).

**Edit**. Regarding the question of whether $df$ is always of the form $a dx + b (dx)^2+\dots+(dx)^n$.

As I mentioned before, Grant makes a series of informal but intuitive statements. One could choose different methods to formalize these informal statements, and the answer to the form of $df$ really depends on which method you use. For example, in synthetic analysis we always have $(dx)^2=0$, and hence $(dx)^n=0$ for $n>1$.

There is also something called nonstandard analysis, which is a system that also can be used to formalize the intuitive statements made by Grant. I'm not familiar with that formalism, though.

And of course there is the usual framework that uses limits to formalize calculus, and in this context the expressions $df$ and $dx$ by themselves don't make any sense.

**Edit**. knowing more about the motivation behind the question.

Since you want to know this in order to "cancel a factor $dx$ with the $dx$ in the denominator" you should know that, in all treatments, let it be the standard limit-based calculations, synthetic analysis or nonstandard analysis, every function which has a derivative can be said to "admit a differential which has at least one factor of $dx$ in every term" (this needs to be made rigourous in each of the frameworks, though). In this vague sense, the answer to your question would be "yes" for every differentiable function, and if this is not the case then the function is not differentiable.

For example, here is a calculation that shows the case you mention, as it happens in the usual limit-based framework.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Graphically, the situation is as follows:

[image: discontinuous function]

Then for $x=0$ and any $h\neq 0$ you have

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(h)-f(0)=1-0=1$$

which you could interpret as telling you that "$df=1$ at $x=1$". What happens, then? Well, then the function is not differentiable at $x=0$, so the derivative does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, first of all.So, does this imply that $df$ will always be of the form $a(dx) + b(dx)^2 + ... + k(dx)^n$ since that is how both the sides can be infinitesimals.

Comment: I have edited my question with the last two comments. I will need to spend some time to grasp your answer but it seems like it will clarify my doubt. Please check out my latest comment on the original question in the meanwhile.

Comment: No df will never be of the form as claimed with powers of dx. Powers of dx will only appear in higher order derivatives. The rule is $df=f' dx$

Comment: And both $df$ and $dx$ make sense in the language of differential forms. In this context we may define exterior powers and tensor powers of forms that formalize the intuitive notions

Comment: @Teddyboer Yeah if you use differential forms that's what you get, but I mean $df$ and $dx$ don't make sense by themselves in the context of a first calculus course. That's one of the reasons I don't like Leibniz's notation hahah. I'm not sure it's quite a good idea for me to talk about differential forms when someone who is just learning how to differentiate asks me about the notation $df/dx$.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz If you're familiar with 3Blue1Brown's methods, he mentioned in a video that he doesn't like to think of $dx$ as an infinitesimal but rather as a finite number that approaches $0$. So, he is basically talking about limits, right? Does that mean that in the context of his videos, $dx = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\Delta x$ and he kind of simplifies the expression inside the limit first and then evaluates it by turning every term which includes a power of $dx$ to $0$?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Mhm not exactly, because $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\Delta x = 0$. Rather, he is using the notation $df/dx$ as an aid to make claims that are intuitive enough.

Comment: It's important for you to be aware that what 3B1B does is not a formal deduction, but an attempt to give intuitive explanation for certain concepts in calculus.

Comment: Oh, right, $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\Delta x$ totally changed the meaning. I get that his videos are meant for intuition and for developing interest in Calculus. I see why limits are a much better framework too now, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help :D. Grant (and I guess others too) already did an excellent work getting you interested in these topics. Now it's your turn to keep reading about what interests you. Good luck.

Comment: @Jackozee Hakkiuz I agree with you that differential forms are overkill for beginners. I just wanted to point out that there is a way of making sense of this. When I was a beginner I was always wondering in what context "calculus with differentials" is explained properly

Comment: @Teddyboer Oh yes I can agree with that. Moreover, there are *various* ways of making sense of this: take a look at the book A primer of infinitesimal analysis by John L. Bell. Intuitionistic logic allows him to give a synthetic account of calculus, without the need of ever looking at limits.

Comment: In this sense, exterior and tensor calculus is (or at least I see it) a higher level language that allows one to take calculus to more general contexts like manifolds.
On the other hand, synthetic analysis takes a different view on calculus from the get-go. These ideas are also used in more general differentiable spaces, which is known as synthetic differential geometry.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar questions when I saw these notations in physics classes when I started studying maths. The most mathematically accurate way is to interpret $df$ and $dx$ in terms of differential forms.
Say $f$ is a smooth function and $x$ a coordinate. The differential of $f$ at some $x_0$, $df(x_0)$, is defined as a linear map $df(x_0):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x_0+h) - f(x_0)= df(x_0)\cdot h + \phi(h),$$ where $\phi$ is some function such that $\phi(h)/h \to 0$ for $h\to 0$. Hence $df(x_0)$ is the linear approximation of $f$ around $x_0$. Now interpret $x$ as the identity function $\text{id}(x) = x$. Replacing $f$ by $\text{id}$ in the formula above, we find $$h = dx(x_0)\cdot h+\phi(h)$$ and it follows that $dx(x_0) = \text{id}$ and $\phi = 0$. Thus, the differential $dx$ of $x$ is nothing but the identity again and we may omitt the point $x_0$. We can verify the following relation between $df(x_0)$ and $dx$: $$df(x_0) = f'(x_0)dx.$$
This is what eventually justifies writing $\frac{df}{dx}=f'(x_0)$. This is indeed the most accurate definition of a derivative of a function/map. There is no obvious way how to define powers $(dx)^2, (dx)^3,...$ in a mathematical way. But it is possible of course. To make sense of it, one needs the notion of tensor product and/or wedge product, but I will skip that here.
A very intuitive introduction into the subject is Do Carmo's "Differential Forms and Applications" but one needs some basic analysis and linear algebra to read it.

To answer your question. Saying that $df_2 = c+adx$ doesn't make sense unless $c=0$. The formal mathematical reason is that $df_2$ must be a linear function and the additive constant breaks linearity. Intuitively, we want to think of $df_2$ as a infinitely small perturbation so we must have $df_2\to 0$ as $dx\to 0$.

Also, your examples are incorrect. It is $d(x^2) = 2xdx$, $d(x^3) = 3x^2 dx$ and so on (just apply the formula $df = f'(x_0) dx$).
(Tensor - )Powers of differentials will come into play if one wants to derivatives of higher order formally.

Comment: If we don't take $(dx)^n$ for $n  \in \Bbb N$ and $n \geq 2$ as $0$, then my examples are not wrong, right?

Comment: Actually, a fairly simple way of defining powers $(dx)^k$ is as follows: we interpret $dx$ as a $1$-form (in this case on $\Bbb{R}$), which in this special case reduces to saying that for all $p \in \Bbb{R}$ and all $v\in T_p\Bbb{R}\cong\Bbb{R}$, $dx_p(v) = v \in \Bbb{R}$. In this case this may seem like a pretty contrived way of writing something simple, but in higher dimensions, this is indeed very natural (the one-dimensional case obscures some of the structure because of various isomorphisms). Now, we interpret $(dx)^k$ to mean a $k^{th}$ order polynomial mapping on the tangent spaces

Comment: So, evaluated pointwise for $p\in \Bbb{R}$, $(dx_p)^k$ could be interpreted as the mapping $T_p\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $v \mapsto (dx_p(v))^k$. So, for example, $(dx)^2$ is the quadratic form associated to the $(0,2)$-tensor field $dx \otimes dx$. Or in words, we're taking the $x$-component of the displacement vector $v$ (this is $dx_p(v)$... and in 1D there's only one direction so this just equals $v$) and raising it to the $k^{th}$ power. THis is a fairly natural construction. (but I like your answer +1)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Actually, I'm still in 10th grade and an absolute beginner to calculus and thus, I am not familiar with terms like 'tensor field'. Is there some way I can interpret this answer and your comments?

Comment: Well in order to define these things carefully you need some quite serious mathematical knowledge. The language is that of "differential forms" as peek-a-bro and I pointed out. As a rule of thumb, just notice that you may only compute with differential of first order (no powers) as if they were numbers. And the rule $df=f' dx$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with how you're defining the differential $df$. Usually, it is defined as $df(x,\Delta x) \equiv f'(x) \Delta x$. For small enough increments $\Delta x$ this becomes $df=f'(x)dx$. All terms which are nonlinear with respect to $dx$ are discarded by definition. So, $f(x)=x^2 \implies df = 2x\cdot dx$. This is motivated by considering $\Delta y \equiv f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)$ which satisfies $\Delta y = f'(x)\Delta x + \epsilon = df(x) + \epsilon$ where the error term $\epsilon$ satisfies $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\epsilon}{\Delta x} =0 $ Definied as such, the differential of a functions represents the principal (linear) part of the increment of the function.

If you want a more explicit treatment of differentials as infinitesimal quantities, you should check out nonstandard analysis which makes use of the hyperreal numbers.